# VBA: How to best store triplets of information together

Tags: vba

I need to find some rows by searching for what the rows is called, which is stored in column A. So far, every time I need to do this, I have called the function (`FindRow`) in a new line. Meaning my code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public fRowType As Long
Public fRowClosing As Long
Public fRowHPPlanDate As Long
Public fRowLoan As Long
Public fRowDoS As Long
Public fRowShare As Long
Public fRowInvestmentType As Long
Public fRowObjectNumber As Long
Public fRowObjectName As Long
Public fRowRisk As Long
Public fRowMacro As Long
Public fRowCountry As Long
Public fRowCity As Long
Public fRowConstruction As Long
Public fRowModernization As Long
Public fRowUsage As Long
Public fRowHPPlanYear As Long
Public fRowHP As Long
Public fRowInterest As Long
Public fRowBorrowed As Long
Public fRowLTV As Long
Public fRowEquity As Long
Public fRowSPVRev As Long
Public fRowSPVExp As Long
Public fRowNCF As Long
Public fRowIRR As Long
Public fRowIRRIM As Long
Public fRowCapRate As Long
Public fRowNOIAcq As Long
Public fRowLeased As Long
Public fRowRentalUnits As Long
Public fRowParking As Long
Public fRowTotalArea
Public fRowRent As Long
Public fRowNOI As Long
Public fRowWalt As Long
Public fRowPriceNet As Long
Public fRowExchange As Long
Public fRowCurrency As Long
Public fRowPriceGross As Long
Public fRowGIK As Long
Public fRowBook As Long
Public fRowMarketValue As Long
Public fRowMarketValuePerc As Long
Public fRowDeterminationMarketValue
Public fRowRepatriation As Long
Public fRowSalesPrice As Long

Sub Test()
    Call DefiningRows(ActiveSheet)
End Sub

Sub DefiningRows(ws As Worksheet) 
    fRowType = FindRow("Type", "A")
    fRowClosing = FindRow("Closing", "A")
    fRowHPPlanDate = FindRow("Holding Period Plan Date (BP)", "A")
    fRowLoan = FindRow("End of Loan", "A")
    fRowDoS = FindRow("Date of Sale", "A")
    fRowShare = FindRow("BVK-Share (%)", "A")
    fRowInvestmentType = FindRow("Investmet Type", "A")
    fRowObjectNumber = FindRow("Objectnumber", "A")
    fRowObjectName = FindRow("Objectname", "A")
    fRowRisk = FindRow("Risk Allocation", "A")
    fRowMacro = FindRow("Macro Allocation", "A")
    fRowCountry = FindRow("Country", "A")
    fRowCity = FindRow("City", "A")
    fRowConstruction = FindRow("Construction Year", "A")
    fRowModernization = FindRow("Modernization Year", "A")
    fRowUsage = FindRow("Main Usage", "A")
    fRowHPPlanYear = FindRow("Holding Period Plan Year (BP)", "A")
    fRowHP = FindRow("Holding Period Plan Year (BP)", "A") + 2
    fRowInterest = FindRow("Interest on debt (ytd.)", "A") + 1
    fRowBorrowed = FindRow("Borrowed Capital (Delta)", "A") + 1
    fRowLTV = FindRow("LTV (Delta)", "A") + 1
    fRowEquity = FindRow("Equity Investment (Delta)", "A") + 1
    fRowSPVRev = FindRow("SPV Revenues (ytd.)", "A") + 1
    fRowSPVExp = FindRow("SPV Expenses (ytd.)", "A") + 1
    fRowNCF = FindRow("NCF (ytd.)", "A") + 1
    fRowIRRIM = FindRow("IRR (IM)", "A")
    fRowIRR = FindRow("IRR (Forecast)", "A") + 1
    fRowCapRate = FindRow("CapRate (Acquisition)", "A") + 1
    fRowLeased = FindRow("Leased Area (m²)", "A") + 1
    fRowRentalUnits = FindRow("Rental Units", "A", PartOrWhole:=xlPart)
    fRowParking = FindRow("Parking Spaces", "A")
    fRowTotalArea = FindRow("Total Area (m²)", "A")
    fRowRent = FindRow("Contractual Rent", "A") + 1
    fRowNOI = FindRow("NOI (ytd.)", "A") + 1
    fRowWalt = FindRow("WALT", "A") + 1
    fRowPriceNet = FindRow("Purchase Price (net)", "A") + 1
    fRowExchange = FindRow("Exchange Rate", "A")
    fRowCurrency = FindRow("Currency", "A")
    fRowPriceGross = FindRow("Purchase Price (gross)", "A") + 1
    fRowGIK = FindRow("Total Costs (GIK)", "A") + 1
    fRowBook = FindRow("Book Value", "A") + 1
    fRowMarketValue = FindRow("Market Value", "A") + 1
    fRowMarketValuePerc = FindRow("Market Value", "A")
    fRowDeterminationMarketValue = FindRow("Determination of market value", "A")
    fRowSalesPrice = FindRow("Sales Price", "A")
    fRowRepatriation = FindRow("Equity Repatriation", "A")
End Sub

Function FindRow(ByVal searchTerm As String, ByVal col As String, Optional ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal PartOrWhole As XlLookAt = xlWhole) As Long
    Dim searchRng   As Range            ' the range to search, based on the column passed to the function
    Dim foundCell   As Range            ' the found match
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set searchRng = .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Set foundCell = searchRng.Find(searchTerm, LookAt:=PartOrWhole)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        FindRow = foundCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox searchTerm & " couldn't be found. Macro will continue."
    End If
End Function
```

My idea was to make an array with all the `searchTerm` and loop through it. The problem is, I realized I have three pieces of information each time around: the name of the variable I want to create (like `fRowType` , the `searchTerm` and the rows I add to this (0, 1, 2). I might be overthinking, but I couldn't come up with something and decided to google my problem. One post brought up using a `Collection` object. I tried it, but quickly realized it's probably not a good idea. I didn't even create the array with the variable names because it looked like this:

```
Sub DefiningRows(ws As Worksheet) 'Loop -> is xlPart necessary? if so, separate array

    Dim fRowCollection As Collection
    Set fRowCollection = New Collection

    fRowCollection.Add Array("Type", "Closing", "Holding Period Plan Date (BP)", "End of Loan", "Date of Sale", "BVK-Share (%)", "Investmet Type", "Objectnumber", _
    "Objectname", "Risk Allocation", "Macro Allocation", "Country", "City", "Construction Year", "Modernization Year", "Main Usage", _
    "Holding Period Plan Year (BP)", "Holding Period Plan Year (BP)", "Interest on debt (ytd.)", "Borrowed Capital (Delta)", "Equity Investment (Delta)", _
    "SPV Revenues (ytd.)", "SPV Expenses (ytd.)", "NCF (ytd.)", "IRR (IM)", "IRR (Forecast)", "CapRate (Acquisition)", "NOI (Aquisition)", "Leased Area (m²)", _
    "Parking Spaces", "Total Area (m²)", "Contractual Rent", "NOI (ytd.)", "WALT", "Purchase Price (net)", "Exchange Rate", "Currency", "Purchase Price (gross)", _
    "Total Costs (GIK)", "Book Value", "Market Value", "Market Value", "Determination of market value", "Sales Price", "Equity Repatriation"), "searchTerm"

    fRowCollection.Add Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "additionalRow"

End Sub
```

That doesn't look very readable to me and if I or someone else were to remove something from the array, they'd have to count through the elements to make sure they delete the right entry in `additionalRow` array. Doesn't seem practical.

What's a good way to go about this?

Comment: Do you know anything about creating a `Class` in VBA? You could always just make a custom class to hold your three specific bits of info then, then use a collection to hold many instances of this class.

Comment: @jamheadart No, never used it, but if this is a good reason to learn it, that's great. I've looked it up and it seems to require a bit more reading to get into it, I need to actually write something myself to understand Properties and Get/Let.. Just to get the basic idea/structure right: I'd create a class module, let's say `clsRows`. Would I then define three member variables (`variableName`, `searchTerm`, `additionalRow`) and work from there?

Comment: Or a custom `Type` object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement

Comment: @Alex yeah that's about the gist of it. I am posting an answer with a quick application of how you could use it.

Comment: Please read about the importance of making a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*. There is an awful lot of code posted, most of which isn't relevant for your core question. Surely there is a way for you to write a much shorter code snippet that illustrates the basic question.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry, I usually do this, it's just in some questions in the past I tried it and despite the code working, but then in the process I forgot some minute variations that altered the problem.  I thought in this case it wasn't too bad because a lot of it is repetitive and didn't really need to be read in detail - I know, that's exactly the argument why I could and should shorten it. I'll do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function in your custom class that allows you to hard-code your properties in a neater fashion:

My class now looks like this:

```
Public property1 As Long
Public property2 As String
Public property3 As String

Public Function Add(param1 As Long, param2 As String, param3 As String, ByRef col As Collection) As Collection
  property1 = param1
  property2 = param2
  property3 = param3
  col.Add Me, param2
  Set Add = col
End Function
```

It takes in four parameters - the three properties I want to set AND the collection I want to add the class itself to. Note the `col.Add Me, param2` is using `Me` to add the class itself with `param2` or `property2` (same thing at this point) as the key.

I could then write a function in which I store and return all of my properties aligned together like this:

```
Function GetMyClasses() As Collection

Dim returnCollection As New Collection

Dim f1 As New Class1: f1.Add 10, "Type", "A", returnCollection
Dim f2 As New Class1: f2.Add 20, "Closing", "A", returnCollection
Dim f3 As New Class1: f3.Add 30, "Etc", "B", returnCollection

set GetMyCollection = returnCollection

End Function
```

The `f1`, `f2` nomenclature doesn't matter here, once the collection is returned you don't deal with the class' name, you deal simply deal with the properties in each instance of the class inside the collection:

```
Sub TestMe()
Dim aCollection As New Collection
Set aCollection = GetMyClasses
    MsgBox aCollection("Type").property3
End Sub
```

Again there are many different ways you could approach it and write your own functions to give you the exact syntax you desire but I hope this shows you some more cool things you can do with classes!

Comment: Didn't expect you to write up another example, thanks! Finally got time to work through it. One question: in `Function GetMyClasses` , should it be `Set GetMyClasses = returnCollection` instead of `set GetMyCollection = returnCollection`?

Comment: Oh yeah it should be, that was just a typo, well spotted!

Answer (score 2):

Using a class you could do something like this.

Create a new class called `clsRow` and give it three simple public properties:

[image: Snippet of class]

```
Public Row As Long
Public SearchTerm As String
Public Name As String
```

Now if I have all my property assignments stored in a table on sheet1, for example:

[image: Snippet of Table]

I can create a collection, cycle through the sheet data and populate many instances of my new class with that data row by row, adding it to the collection:

```
Sub example()

Dim myRows As New Collection
Dim c As clsRow

For i = 2 To 11

    Set c = New clsRow

    ' next lines assign the new class properties based on the sheet values
    c.Name = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value2
    c.Row = Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value2
    c.SearchTerm = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value2

    ' next line adds this particular instance of the class
    ' to the collection with a KEY based on the class' name (can use any property)
    myRows.Add c, c.Name ' 
Next i

' I can now use any key to call on any member of the collection
MsgBox myRows("e").SearchTerm
' e.g. will produce "Look 5"
MsgBox myRows("b").Row
' e.g. will produce "10"

End Sub
```

In a nutshell, you plonk all your data definitions in an easily-maintainable place (hidden worksheet?! rather than hard-coding), populate a collection of your custom classes by cycling through that sheet and then you have a whole bunch of data more easily on-call.

There's an infinite amount of ways you can build on this idea, so good luck and have fun!

Comment: Although it's worth noting that if you did have a hidden sheet with all this info on you could probably just use some clever functions using lookups / matches without having to create collections of classes etc...

Comment: I'm thinking it through now and am wondering if it's much of a practical benefit to me (aside from leaning about classes)? If I hardcoded it, I'd have to store the information somehow - which would mean 3 separate arrays (`arrayNames` etc) - before adding it to the user defined class, right ? But 3 arrays would make it difficult to see in the code that "e"  has the `SearchTerm` "look 5". 

So there's no way to somhow save it as a triplet? Like `c.Add ("a", 5, "look1")`?

Comment: Using custom classes you can create your own functions which means you can create your own `Add` type functions - I've posted another answer which lets you make the syntax you want more achievable.